# NetLogo: more than one boolean in ifelse-value

Tags: if-statement, variables, boolean, netlogo, systemdynamics

for one variable in my System Dynamics Model in NetLogo i would like to have more than one boolean in my ifelse-value.

I tried it with the following code that I used as the expression for the variable.

```
(ifelse-value
    quality = 100 [ 1.1 ]
    quality = 80 [ 1.4 ]
    quality = 60 [ 0.8 ]
               [ 0.7 ])
```

I got the following error:

```
IFELSE-VALUE expected 3 inputs, a TRUE/FALSE, a reporter block and a reporter block.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That code looks right to me assuming you have a variable named `quality` defined somewhere.  Are you using at least NetLogo 6.1?  The multi-clause version of `ifelse-value` it was added in that release.  Docs: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#ifelse-value

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I have a stock named quality which is linked to the variable. I didn't know about the new version of NetLogo, I am now using 6.0.4. That might cause the problem! Thank  you!